# Append method overwrites previous values in a loop

Tags: python, list, matplotlib

I'm making a python app that sorts random values without using `sort()`. I proceeded by making a loop that compares every element in the list with the one that comes after it, then I added an if statement that swaps the two values if the first value is bigger than the second.

Then I added a loop that repeats the above-mentioned action the number of times the length of the list. The sorter works but I wanted to create an empty list that every time the list changes, it appends to the previous content of the empty list but the list itself is being overwritten every time.

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
if __name__ == '__main__' :
    mylist = [*range(1, 5)]
    random.shuffle(mylist)
    liste1 = mylist
    print(liste1)
    liste2 = []
    plt.ion()
    def tester() :
        for i in range(0,3) :
            if liste1[i] < liste1[i + 1] :
                y = liste1[i]
                liste1[i] = liste1[i + 1]
                liste1[i + 1] = y

        else :
                pass


    for j in range(0, 3) :
        liste2.append(liste1)
        tester()
    print(liste1)
    print(liste2)


    x = np.array(liste1)

    for t in liste2 :
        plt.clf()
        c = np.array(liste1)
        plt.plot(x, c)
        plt.pause(1)
        plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you edit your description a little bit so we can clearly understand what the problem is?

Comment: Okay, I think I understand the issue now. I am working on it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this help:

```
lst = []
for n in range(10):
    lst2 = [a,b,c] # Add whatever necessary to list
    lst.append(lst2) # Add the list to the other list
```

Comment: Although this is how you append a list to a list, it does not work in this implementation because the original array is constantly changing.

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned up your code so it would be easier for both you and other people, in the future, to read. I also fixed your sorting algorithm. I saw that you were trying to implement bubble sort but you need two loops for that. I added that in so now you should be sorting correctly and you should be able to print out each step of the sort.

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
if __name__ == '__main__' :
    mylist = [*range(1, 5)]
    random.shuffle(mylist)
    liste1 = mylist

    a = liste1
    print("Before:", a)
    b = list()
    c = list()
    print("===========================")
    for i in range(len(a) -1):
      for j in range(len(a) - i - 1):
          if(a[j] > a[j + 1]):
              temp = a[j]
              a[j] = a[j + 1]
              a[j + 1] = temp
          b.append(a[:]) # The [:] is VERY important
          print(b)
    print("===========================")
    print("Final:", b)

    liste2 = b
    x = np.array(liste1)
    plt.ion()
    for t in liste2 :
        plt.clf()
        c = np.array(liste1)
        plt.plot(x, c)
        plt.pause(1)
        plt.show()
```

Comment: If this helped you, I would appreciate it if you accept this answer :)

Comment: thaks !! it worked really well . can you just explain why the [:] is very important ?

Comment: It takes the most recent order of all of the elements in "a." Before, you had "a" overwriting itself but [:] prevents that from happening.

Comment: thank you i added it to my code and it works aswell !